# pandas.PeriodIndex causes ipython kernal to 'die unexpectedly' when initializing with an array of datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Here's what I can do to recreate this issue:

```
In [2]: num = range(11)

In [3]: from netCDF4 import num2date

In [4]: time.units
Out[4]: u'days since 1859-12-01'

In [5]: time.calendar
Out[5]: u'360_day'

In [6]: dates = num2date(num, time.units, time.calendar)

In [7]: dates
Out[7]: 
array([1859-12-01 00:00:00, 1859-12-02 00:00:00, 1859-12-03 00:00:00,
       1859-12-04 00:00:00, 1859-12-05 00:00:00, 1859-12-06 00:00:00,
       1859-12-07 00:00:00, 1859-12-08 00:00:00, 1859-12-09 00:00:00,
       1859-12-10 00:00:00, 1859-12-11 00:00:00], dtype=object)

In [8]: import pandas as pd

In [9]: idx = pd.PeriodIndex(dates, freq='d')

In [10]: It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
```

I have a list or array (I tried both) of numeric values representing the number of days from a given date with a given calendar (all from a netCDF4 file containing climate model data).

First I convert the numeric data to an array of datetime objects using `netCDF4.num2date` as shown. Next I load the dates in using `pandas.PeriodIndex` with a daily frequency. Shortly after this my kernel dies. I've tried this a number of times and the issue is very re-creatable for me. Any ideas on what the cause of this problem is or how to mitigate the issue would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: The problem stems from that fact that I am using an irregular calendar in `num2date` which violates the fact that `pandas.PeriodIndex` needs to have regular intervals**

Comment: What type is in the `dates` array?  Could you should `dates[0]`

Comment: each element in the array is a datetime object `dates[0]
Out[15]: 1859-12-01 00:00:00`

Comment: Sorry, could you show `type(dates[0])`  A python datetime will repr as `datetime(1859, ...)` so I'm guessing it's something else?

Comment: No worries! `type(dates[0])
Out[22]: instance
` from the matplotlib docs `Return value is a datetime instance in timezone tz (default to rcparams TZ value).

If x is a sequence, a sequence of datetime objects will be returned`. netCDF4.num2date should be the same only with support for alternate calendars

Comment: As I mentioned in the edit the problem comes from the irregular calendar (I tried with standard and it did in fact work). pandas.DatetimeIndex is also not an option because I have dates exceeding the year 2263. I wonder if there is a way to somehow get a data frame with this timestamp information for resampling, grouping, slicing, etc.

Comment: This probably won't fit super cleanly into pandas since your calendar has days that aren't 'real' (e.g. Feb 30th).  Have you thought about something to the effect of storing month/day/year in separate integer columns, so you can at least work with the data?

Comment: Actually that might make the most sense. I only need certain statistics from the datafame not a clean timeseries per se anyhow